# Is it possible to attach VS2012 debugger to WCF service running on local IIS 8 webserver

Tags: wcf, debugging, iis, visual-studio-2012

As the title says, I have a WCF service that is published to a IIS 8 web server running on the same machine. Is it possible to debug this? The client calling the service is running in a different solution and different instance of Visual Studio.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As the title says, I have a WCF service that is published to a IIS 8
>   web server running on the same machine. Is it possible to debug this?

Sure, with the solution containing the WCF code open, go to `Debug -> Attach to Process` and select the `w3wp.exe` process in the list of processes that corresponds to your application. This will start the Debug mode and you could place breakpoints in the source code.

Comment: I don't have any w3p.exe (or anything close) in the list, even if I tick the box "Show processes from all users". And yeah, I can call the service from my client application. Any ideas? Also, Windows 8 if that makes any difference.

Comment: After some fiddling with the web server, it now appears (but with the name w3wp.exe of course).

Comment: You are correct, the name is `w3wp.exe`. I have updated my answer to fix my mistake. This process will be spawned by IIS once the application is started (i.e. you have sent at least one HTTP request to it).

Comment: If the `w3wp.exe` process is not displayed, try browsing to a site in IIS and then refresh the list. This will spin up the `w3wp.exe` process if it is not already displayed.

Comment: any way to debug wcf service which hosted in another pc.

Answer (score 0):

what I did is simple and it works for me, I had to add another console project then on the reference I added the WCF from that same solution, then you can access the wcf, one thing that you have to aware is that, you will also need to add connectionstring on App.Config (console app) since it will fail on connection when you start doing the debugging.

hope that helps.